# Joomla RSForm Pro - Make a field as readonly in edit submission directory list

Tags: content-management-system, joomla3.0

I want to make a particular field as read-only in Joomla RSForm Pro Edit Submissions Directory list.

Screenshot for editing the records. Listing submission records within this records i want to make a particular field "Container Number" as read-only.

[image]

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla question on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Add `readonly="readonly"` under attributes.